# Ошибка при компиляции java программы: unreported exception SQLException

Tags: linux, map-reduce, java, компиляция, sql

Привожу часть `hadoop` программы, породившую ошибки компиляции

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
//import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class ParallelIndexation {
    //public static native long Traveser(String Path);

    //public static native void Configure(String Path);

    //static {
    //  System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
    //}
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Map.class.getName());
        //DOMConfigurator.configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j.xml");

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            int CountComputers;
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/countcomputers.txt");
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String result=br.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            input.close();
            fstream.close();
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;    
               String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch";
                String user = "postgres";
                String password = "valter89";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            /* StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                paths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            } */
            while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString("1")); };
```

При компиляции программы с помощью команды

```
root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin# ./javac -classpath /export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar:/folder/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar -d /folder/classes /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java &> jdbc.txt
```

и получил в результате следующие ошибки

```
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:56: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                                             ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:57: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    st = con.createStatement();
                                            ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:58: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    rs = st.executeQuery("select path from tasks order by id");
                                        ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:64: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString("1")); };
                          ^
/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java:64: error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            while (rs.next()) { paths.add(rs.getString("1")); };
                                                      ^
5 errors
```

Помогите устранить эти ошибки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вань, установи себе нормальный IDE (Intellij IDEA или Eclipse) хватить геройствовать со строчным компилятором... IDE сразу тебе сообщит причину ошибок даже без компиляции и предложит охватить блоком `try-catch` нужный участок

Answer (score 3):

Вам компилятор четко сообщает причину ошибки компиляции: вызываемые методы выбрасывают checked исключение SQLException и вы должны либо обработать его, либо объявить выбрасываемым из метода.